# ¿Como cambiar el estatus de una fecha mayor a la fecha actual en sistema?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

No puedo introducir el status 1 que es pendiente, introduce a todos como 2 que es vencido y el 3 lo estoy manejando con un id independiente para saber si ya esta pagado o no

```
$sql =  "UPDATE calendar SET status = 1 where finish_at > CURDATE() and status!=3)";
$sql1 = "UPDATE calendar SET status = 2 where finish_at <= CURDATE() and status!=3 and status!=1";
$sql2 = "UPDATE calendar SET status = 3 where Pagado = 1";
```

- Lo que quiero es que pueda introducir valores mayores a la fecha del
  dia de hoy
  [image: Calendar]

Comment: ¿Qué datos tienes en la tabla `calendar`? Igual no te los cambia porque ninguno cumple las condiciones que pides

Comment: @DavidJP te adjunte mis datos de calendar

Comment: Ejecuta un `SHOW CREATE TABLE calendar;` y dinos qué muestra. Al menos por el formato tus columnas `start_at` y `finish_at` no parecen ser del tipo `DATE`. En las bases de datos las columnas de tipo `DATE` deben tener el formato `yyyy-mm-dd`. Si no has definido esas columnas del tipo `DATE` te recomiendo que lo hagas (puedes crear dos nuevas columnas con el tipo adecuado y actualizarlas en base a los datos existentes en las antiguas columnas, finalmente borrar las columnas viejas y renombrar las nuevas). Si no normalizas vas a arrastrar con muchísimos problemas en el futuro.

Comment: Te sugeriría cambiar los tiempos a formatos timestamp para que sea más fácil manipularlas

Comment: No tienes ningún dato que cumpla la primera condición, ¿no? El `3` dejó de cumplirla hace dos días... Por eso no tienes ningún `status=1`